# IP routing Solaris 9 access the internet from local network

Tags: unix, netstat, ip-forwarding, iproute

I am trying to configure the NICS on the Solaris Sparc server.
My problem lies in getting out to the "Internet" from the local network.
I have requested the NIC to receive a DHCP server address

```
#ifconfig -interface dhcp start.
```

If anyone could guide me as to what I need to do next.
I am not able to ping 4.2.2.2 or access the internet.
Much appreciated, thank you

```
#uname -a
SunOS dev 5.9 Generic_122300-59 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210

ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=1000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 8232 index 1
     inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
bge0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 10.100.0.3 netmask ffffc000 broadcast 10.100.63.255
bge0:2: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 10.100.0.22 netmask ffffc000 broadcast 10.100.63.255
bge3: flags=1004843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DHCP,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 12
    inet 169.14.60.37 netmask fffffe00 broadcast 169.14.61.255


cat /etc/defaultrouter
10.100.0.254
169.14.60.1

cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 169.14.96.73
nameserver 169.10.8.4

netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref   Use   Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---------
169.14.60.37         169.14.60.1          UGH       1      0
169.14.60.0          169.14.60.37         U         1     18  bge3
10.100.0.0           10.100.0.3           U         1  34940  bge0
10.100.0.0           10.100.0.22          U         1      0  bge0:2
224.0.0.0            10.100.0.3           U         1      0  bge0
default              10.100.0.254         UG        1    111
default              169.14.60.1          UG        1     26
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH       10  59464  lo0

bash-2.05$ sudo ndd -get /dev/ip bge0:ip_forwarding
1
bash-2.05$ sudo ndd -get /dev/ip bge3:ip_forwarding
1
bash-2.05$ sudo ndd -get /dev/ip ip_forwarding
1
```

Comment: You make a point of showing the ip_forwarding settings - why?  Are you trying to use this solaris machine as a NAT gateway?   Explain more about the network topology.

Comment: You've got two default gateways. That may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine looks like to be properly configured as a DHCP client.

Either your company doesn't allow a direct connection from its internal network to the Internet or the DHCP server is not configured to provide the correct default router.

In any case, nothing you can fix without asking for help to the network admins.

Comment: I have a windows server in the network.
One NIC is connected to the local network and the other NIC to the outside network.
When I added the 169.14.60.1 as the second gateway I was able to connect to the internet as well as talk to the local servers in the 10.100.x.x network.

Comment: It is unclear what machine you are talking about but in any case, if you need to manually add a gateway to connect to the Internet, your DHCP configuration is to blame. Another reason that would explain why you can't connect is your machine is not allowed by firewall rules.